# How to perform regex substitutions on chapter including theirs numbers with Calibre?

Tags: regex, replace, epub, calibre

I have the following sequence in a epub file:
`CHAPTER 1`
`CHAPTER 2`
`CHAPTER 3`
I want to add a head tag for each of them, so i use the replacement module of Calibre:
`Find: CHAPTER *`
`Replace with:<h1>CHAPTER</h1>`

But i only obtain this:
`<h1>CHAPTER</h1>1`
`<h1>CHAPTER</h1>2`
`<h1>CHAPTER</h1>3`
... with the chapter number outside the h1 tag. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)** don't work like **[wildcard characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_character)**.

Indeed, the regex `CHAPTER *` means : "`CHAPTER` followed by none or several spaces".

You need to catch the string `"CHAPTER"` followed by at least one blank character then by a number (integer).

So, you should write :

```
Find: CHAPTER (\d+)
Replace with:<h1>CHAPTER \1</h1>
```

Here, `(\d+)` is a sequence of at least one (`+`) digit (`\d`). The enclosing parentheses **capture** this sequence and store it as `\1`

You should read the [Quick reference for regexp syntax](https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/regexp_quick_reference.html) of Calibre for more details.

Comment: Thank you so much.